# How can I redefine a variable based on a functions result? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, sharepoint

I have something like the following:

```
$('#country1').change(function() {
    var hrc = "Yes";
    if (className == "HR") {
        var hrc = "Yes";
        return true;
    } else {
        var hrc = "No";
        return false;
    }
```

Then I am pulling this with JSON into a SP List like:

```
$('.submitdataAccounts').on('click', function() {
    var data = {
        __metadata: {
            'type': 'SP.Data.ChangeOfAddressListListItem'
        },
        "high_risk_country": hrc,
    };
```

This part works correctly as everything else in the form posts successfully into the list

If I leave it as a static variable at the top of the page it passes correctly but does not work if it's based on the fuction.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable outside the functions, so it is a global variable, and then you can acces it everywhere in your code. If you give a global variable an another value, it is redefined and gets that value until an another value change.